# How to get 20% the total number of file in a folder?

Tags: bash, shell

I am using shell to count the number files of a folder. For example, a folder `A` has 100 file, and I just want to show 20% of it and it must be integer, means 20. This is my code but it was failure

```
file_num= find . -type f | wc -l
prob_select=0.2
file_num=$(expr $file_num \* $prob_select)
file_num=$( printf "%.0f" $file_num)
```

Comment: What exactly is "fails"? Error? Wrong output?

Comment: What order should be considered when selecting 20% of the files, from the top/bottom or by modification/created date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a somewhat simpler approach which shows every *n* files instead of requiring you to know how many there are before deciding which ones to display,

```
find . -type f | awk -v factor=5 'NR%factor == 0'
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked. the factor is 5  means 20%, right?

Comment: Yeah, one in five.

Answer (score 2):

You can't work with float numbers like that in bash, but try to convert 20% -> 0.2 -> 2/10 -> 1/5, so: 
`file_num=$(($(find . -type f | wc -l) / 5)); echo "${file_num}"`

You will get the number of 20% of found files.
Next, just run `find . -type f | head -n "${file_num}"`

Comment: The OP doesn't do any FP arithmetic in bash. He is using `expr`.